# How do I get my iPhone-only app to run on iPads? (constraint question?)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, interface-builder

My iPhone-only Objective-C app (iPad not checked) runs correctly on SE 2nd up to iPhone 12 Pro Max, properly centered, fully functional, but is stretched and clipped on any iPad (in Simulator--I blanked center content below re privacy), and on some I get black screens.  Every element is constrained ultimately centered on Superview X and Y centers (nothing absolute); is that the problem?  Is there a typical problem that keeps iPhone-only apps from appearing properly on iPads?  The app in no way does anything special for iPads.  Is there a good tutorial about this subject? Thanks[image: I blanked some proper content re privacy.]

Comment: You might have opted for only iPhone not iPad.. To be able to achieve layout using same storyboards, you need to follow these

1. Opt the app for iPhone and iPad both.
2. Your screen will stretch to full screen to prevent that you just need to add leading and trailing variation constant on the parent view of each ViewController which will adjust on iPad

Comment: Yes, I said I opted for iPhone only.  I'm not trying to make a universal app (I also don't want to be forced to forever maintain an iPad version)--iPhone size on iPad is fine.  What I get with iPhone only is the correct launch storyboard in the size of iPhone, but then the main storyboard image is stretched a bit and clipped to the same physical size of the launch storyboard.

Comment: Buttons on the left, right and bottom are clipped at the boundary, as is a text entry field at the top. If I click iPad, the launch screen is full screen height with gray stripes left and right, but the then the main screen turns black. Is there a common newbie mistake here? Maybe something about my constrains is a common mistake?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simply that constraints sufficient for all iPhones are not necessarily sufficient for iPhone in iPad.  Just because the app is sized correctly for all iPhones doesn't mean it's correct for iPhone in iPad.  That's what this newbie learned!